# PasswordBox weird behaviour in Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, passwordbox

I am trying to use a `PasswordBox` in my Windows 10 universal application. The problem that I am facing is that if I am pre-populating a `PasswordBox` with some text before the user has any chance to type in it, the reveal button is not shown anymore. This does not happen if I am populating the `PasswordBox` while the app is running. I also tried with/without the recommended `PasswordRevealMode` and the deprecated `IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled`, but no luck.

This is a small snippet to demonstrate the problem:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Pre-populated:"/>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="PrePopulatedPasswordBox"
        PasswordRevealMode="Peek"
        Password="123456"
    />
    <TextBlock Text="Type to populate"/>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="PopulatedWhenRunningPasswordBox"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I don't think that this is the intended behaviour (as far as I understood from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-uS/office/office365/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.aspx)

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry...is a typo. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `PasswordRevealMode` property [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.passwordrevealmode), it would seem like this is known behavior:

> If the PasswordBox loses focus and then regains focus, the reveal button is not shown again unless the password is cleared and character entry starts over.

Since the field is pre-populated, the reveal button will not show unless the password field changes.  Maybe this isn't the best behavior, but it does seem to be "working as designed".